# Python function returns nan

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, nan

I have written function for gradient descent and used pandas to read csv file. But when I use data read by pandas, the function returns "nan". I can't understand why.

Thanks in advance.

```
def gradient_descent(X, Y, w, b, alpha):

    dl_dw = 0.0
    dl_db = 0.0

    N = len(X)

    for i in range(N):
        dl_dw += -1*float(X[i]) * (float(Y[i]) - (w*float(X[i]) + b))
        dl_db += -1*(float(Y[i]) - (float(w*X[i]) + b))


    w = w - (1/float(N)) * dl_dw * alpha
    b = b - (1/float(N)) * dl_db * alpha

return w, b

import pandas as pd                         
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")               
print(data.head())                          

X = data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1) 
Y = data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)

print(gradient_descent(X, Y, 0.0, 0.0, 100))
```

Comment: It would definitely help if you could identify which training data produce nan results and show those data to us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a vanishing gradient problem. You gradients might be very close or even zero.
Try to initialize your weights with non zero values.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing the alpha value to something like 0.01 or so. and make sure that your dataframe doesn't have any null values

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding from train.csv, if it is UTF-8|UTF-16...
You can check it, opening train.csv in VSCode.
Example: if train.csv is UTF-16 LE, you can fix with pd.read_csv('train.csv',encoding='UTF-16 LE')

Comment: Hi sir, I check it and it is encoding='cp1252'. I modified the code as data = pd.read_csv("train.csv", encoding='cp1252'), but it didn't work

Comment: Can you copy the output of that print?

Comment: x          y
0  24.0  21.549452
1  50.0  47.464463
2  15.0  17.218656
3  38.0  36.586398
4  87.0  87.288984
(nan, nan)